# Why i get error:incompatible types: AdapterView<CAP#1> cannot be converted?

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to cast the parent object of OnItemSelected method to retrieve the object of the selected item but there is an error

```
TextView output = null;
CustomAdapter adapter;
MainActivity activity = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    activity  = this;

    Spinner  SpinnerExample = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    output                  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.company);

    // Set data in arraylist
    setListData();

    // Resources passed to adapter to get image
    Resources res = getResources();

    // Create custom adapter object ( see below CustomAdapter.java )
    adapter = new CustomAdapter(activity, R.layout.spinner_rows, CustomListViewValuesArr,res);

    // Set adapter to spinner
    SpinnerExample.setAdapter(adapter);

    // Listener called when spinner item selected
    SpinnerExample.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View v, int position, long id) {
            // your code here
           SpinnerModel obj = (SpinnerModel) parentView;

            // Get selected row data to show on screen
            String Company    = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.company)).getText().toString();
            String CompanyUrl = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.sub)).getText().toString();

            String OutputMsg = "Selected Company : \n\n"+Company+"\n"+CompanyUrl;


            Toast.makeText(
                    getApplicationContext(),OutputMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Toast.makeText(
                    getApplicationContext(),xxx.getCompanyName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

---

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SpinnerModel>{

private Activity activity;
private ArrayList data;
public Resources res;
SpinnerModel tempValues=null;
LayoutInflater inflater;

/*************  CustomAdapter Constructor *****************/
public CustomAdapter(
        MainActivity activitySpinner,
        int textViewResourceId,
        ArrayList objects,
        Resources resLocal
)
{
    super(activitySpinner, textViewResourceId, objects);

    /********** Take passed values **********/
    activity = activitySpinner;
    data     = objects;
    res      = resLocal;

    /***********  Layout inflator to call external xml layout () **********************/
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}
```

When compile i get Error:(48, 50) error: incompatible types: AdapterView cannot be converted to SpinnerModel
where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
CAP#1 extends Adapter from capture of ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the `SpinnerModel` object associated to the clicked item, you should get it from the adapter:

```
SpinnerModel obj = adapter.getItem(position);
```

`parentView` is the `SpinnerExample` object.